# What made the Starfleet Academy ring (of power) into a bomb?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

Early in the film, we see Thomas Harewood drop the said [ring](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_Academy_ring) into a glass of water which reacts violenty and creates a massive explosion.

**What made the ring into a bomb?**

---

This post on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/269inc/star_trek_how_does_the_ring_bomb_work/) includes a suggestion:

> ...it was a TINY amount of antimatter suspended in a TINY magnetic field in the ring. When the ring dissolved in the water, the containment failed and the small amount of antimatter reacted with the water/ring remains/etc.

Is there any evidence to support this?

Comment: The fires of Mount Doom.

Comment: @RogueJedi, https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AZYEkdK5Gfc

Comment: The same reddit also posited that the ring might have been made of a fictional reactive metal. I can't recall anything in the interviews that confirmed or denied either theory.